# RunUMAP code error after merged spatial transcriptomic objects

Tags: pca, seurat

I merged 6 spatial transcriptomic objects together and then ran

```
Metastaticsamples.merge <- ScaleData(Metastaticsamples.merge)

#perform linear reduction analysis:
Metastaticsamples.merge <- RunPCA(Metastaticsamples.merge, features = VariableFeatures(object = Metastaticsamples.merge))

#Metastatic
Metastaticsamples.merge <- FindNeighbors(Metastaticsamples.merge, reduction = "pca", dims = 1:15)
Metastaticsamples.merge <- FindClusters(Metastaticsamples.merge, verbose = FALSE)
Metastaticsamples.merge <- RunUMAP(Metastaticsamples.merge, dims = 1:15)
```

However upon doing RunUMAP i hit an error code

```
20:35:37 Initializing from normalized Laplacian + noise (using irlba)
Error in irlba::irlba(L, nv = n, nu = 0, maxit = iters) :
function 'as_cholmod_sparse' not provided by package 'Matrix'
```

any thoughts on what happened and how to overcome this?

tried to check packages update them but did not work

Comment: Could be a compatibility issue. What do you mean by package update not working? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same error. Yes, it can be resolved by downgrading to `Matrix 1.6-1`. But it's also possible to reinstall `irlba` without the need to downgrade Matrix (which is a temporary workaround). Reinstalling `irlba` worked in my case.

Also see: https://github.com/bwlewis/irlba/issues/70

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, got same error. issue solved after:

```
   install.packages("remotes")
   remotes::install_version("Matrix", version = "1.6-1")
   packageVersion("Matrix")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a compatibility issue with the new Matrix package version (1.6-2). Just install the previous version (1.6-1) and you should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

## Another solution:

### remove Matrix

`remove.packages("Matrix")`

### remove irlba

`remove.packages("irlba")`

### remove Seurat

`remove.packages("Seurat")`

### reinstall Seurat

`remotes::install_version("Seurat", version = "4.3.0.1")`

With the latter installation you reinstall also Matrix and irlba as dependencies of Seurat. In this way you can work with dgcMatrix objects.